# WebStorm - Cmd-Click not working

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm

Pretty new to WebStorm.

Usually, when I <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd> on a directive or CSS class in the code-base, WebStorm opens a new tab with the file from which that code originates from.

Lately though, WebStorm has just been taking me to the same minified file for everything I click on.

Any idea what's going on? I've updated and restarted the program.

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- usually helps in such "suddenly stopped working" situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue for me. I also tried completely shutting down my computer.

Comment: Looks like its a bug in WS 2017. Haven't found a solution yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Do Ctrl + B , you jump to the referenced file or imported module

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/06/10-webstorm-shortcuts-you-need-to-know/

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately, Ctrl/Cmd + B does the same thing.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!